# Посчитать количество вхождений строки в файле

Tags: php, скрипт

Есть скрипт

```
if (strpos(file_get_contents("filename.txt"), "Искомая строка"))
    echo "Искомая строка найдена";  
else
    echo "Искомая строка отсутствует";
```

Он находит "Искомую строку", но она не одна, как подсчитать сколько их в файле?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match-all.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот [substr_count] http://php.net/manual/ru/function.substr-count.php

substr_count — Возвращает число вхождений подстроки

Comment: А куда его прикрутить в моем скрипте, не понимаю, если не сложно)

Comment: `$text = file_get_contents("filename.txt");
echo substr_count($text, 'Искомую строку');
`

Comment: Большое спасибо)